# Socket.IO Emit is emitting to all clients

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, callback, socket.io

So I'm writing an app in NodeJS, and to preface my question please understand how my setup currently works:

I have Clients who connect via Socket.io to "Server X", and then my "Server X" connects via Socket.io to "Server Y", and they all send data back to each other via Socket.io.

Client <---> Server X <---> Server Y

Clients refer to users and their browsers, and then I have a node app running on both my server x and my server y.

So in the code below on my Server X, if you look at line 4 it works exactly as it should. It emits the message ONLY to the client who requested it.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // This works just fine.
    socket.emit('return_login', 'Test Message');

    socket.on('login', function(data){
        // This line correctly sends the data to Server Y
        server_y.emit('login', data);
    });

    server_y.on('return_login', function(data){
        // This emits to all connected clients???
        socket.emit('return_login', data);
    });

});
```

Now my problem is when "Server Y" emits `return_login` to server x, what I want to happen is for server x to take the value emitted by server y and just send it back to the original client, or web browser. But for some reason that line emits to ALL connected clients.

I have a laptop, this computer and my phone all testing this and every time that emit happens it sends to EVERYONE.

If someone could please help me with this I would greatly appreciate it. If I need to post more code please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sending to all clients because you have installed a separate listener for each socket for the `return_login` message.  So, when one client logs in and the `return_login` message is sent back to your server, you have a separate listener for every single socket that sees that message and forwards it to that socket.  In this way, it gets sent to every connected socket.

One way to fix that is to make sure that the `return_login` message is only sent to the socket that it belongs to.  If you can send a socket.id with that message and have that server echo that id back as part of the response, then you can check that when you receive the message to make sure you only send it to the socket that it belongs to.

This is one of the issues with a pure message-based system.  You are trying to do a request/response where only the requester sees the response, but socket.io isn't a request/response system.  A response is sent to all listeners of that particular message and since you have a listener for that message for every single socket that is connected, every single socket is seeing it and then forwarding it on to it's client.

So, with a corresponding modification to the other server to echo back the `id` value, you could do this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // This works just fine.
    socket.emit('return_login', 'Test Message');

    socket.on('login', function(data){
        // add our id so we can identify our response back
        data.id = socket.id;
        server_y.emit('login', data);
    });

    let fn = function(data) {
        // check to see if this message is destined for this socket
        if (data.id === socket.id) {
            // make data copy with id value removed so 
            //   we don't send that to the client
            let tempData = Object.assign({}, data);
            tempData.delete(id);
            socket.emit('return_login', tempData);
            // we're done with this listener so remove it
            server_y.removeListener('return_login', fn);
        }
    });

    server_y.on('return_login', fn);

});
```

---

It might be tempting to just remove your listener for the `return_login` message after you receive it, but that causes a race condition if two clients happen to both be in the process of logging in at the same time and thus both have listeners at the same time, then the first message would be received by both listeners.

Comment: You solved my problem, however I'm still confused. Why are you deleting the socket id from that tempData object? You said in the comment make data copy with id value removed so we don't send that to the client, but wouldn't you WANT to know what socket id they are? Also, I removed the line `server_y.removeListener('return_login', fn);` because it was making it so you could only attempt one login.

Comment: @flakeyjake - The client has no need to know the `socket.id` of the server-side connection so I thought I'd remove it to keep with the same data structure you were sending to the client before.  I see no reason here to want to send it to the client.  If you want to avoid removing it, you can allow it to be sent to the client - no harm.  I didn't know you wanted to login more than once.  Yes, to do that, you would either establish a new listener when you send the login message or not remove it.

Comment: @flakeyjake - Since it looks like you may be new here, if my answer led to a solution for you, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Comment: That makes more sense @jfriend00 , thank you so much for your help! I will mark this as the answer now

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your code. But I usually use room to emit to an user and callback function of socket. This is my solution using callback instead of **return_login** event

```js
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('login', function(data, callback){
        
        // Using callback instead of return_login event
        server_y.emit('login', data, function(responseData){
          
          // put this socket to room as name = user_id
          socket.join(responseData.user_id);
          
          // return result by callback
          callback(responseData)
        });
    });

});

// emit to exactly user_id with return_login event if you want
io.to(user_id).emit('return_login', {key: 'ok'})
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this, however it wasn't exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate the willingness to help though :)